# Jquery on 'load' executing, but commands after not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to have the header's background transparent on 'index.html' and opaque on any other page. I am attempting to do this through Jquery and css.

My header:

```
<div class="nav"> ... </div>
```

CSS for the header:

```
.nav {
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    transition: all 0.2s;
}
```

Here is the code that is supposed to run when the $(window) loads and it determines whether to make the header's background transparent or not by looking for 'index.html' as the path/URL:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    if(document.location.pathname.match(/[^\/]+$/)[0] == 'index.html'){
        $('.nav').removeClass('nav-visible');
        $('.nav').addClass('nav-hidden');
    }
    else {
        $('.nav').addClass('nav-visible');
        $('.nav').removeClass('nav-hidden');
    }
});
```

Here is the simple CSS that makes it visible or not:

```
.nav-visible {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
.nav-hidden {
    background-color: rgba(245, 245, 245, 0);
}
```

Instead of working, the header's background always loads as transparent instead of opaque, no matter the page. The page ('index.html') detection works, I checked. The $(window).on('load'...) also fires, and the if statements work as they should. Just the contents within the if statements.

Comment: What's the result of `document.location.pathname.match(/[^\/]+$/)`?

Comment: returns 'index.html', and the if statement returns true. I put a console.out('if statement is true') in the If statement to test. When it isn't true (like on an 'about.html' page), it goes to the else.

Comment: If you change the HTML to `<div class="nav nav-hidden">` does that hide it? (Just to check that the CSS is loading and the class does what you want it to...)

Comment: What happens if you use [$(document).ready(...)](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) instead of window load?

Comment: it does hide it. And when I do `<div class="nav nav-visible">` it does show the background.

Comment: Same thing happens when I use `$(document).ready(...)`

Comment: Use the DOM inspector to check if the element actually gets those classes set as you expect. And if that is the case, check what CSS rules apply; maybe one with higher specificity overwrites what you are trying to do with those classes.

Comment: try $('.nav')[0].removeClass instead

Comment: Ok I found the issue, I was using jquery to link my `index.html` to a `header.html` so I can make global edits to the header much easier than changing all 10 pages' headers. Everything else in my .js script works on the header but I guess I'm stupid and didn't realize that it was only detecting whether the `index.html` loaded or not, and not the `header.html`. Thanks! Sorry for the trouble :P lesson learned.

Answer (score 1):

Do an alert for the below and see if it is "index.html" in smaller case

```
alert(document.location.pathname.match(/[^\/]+$/)[0]);
```

Okay, $('.nav') will give you an array not a single element, even if its a single element having that css applied, it is an array with a single element. use $('.nav')[0].removeClass

Comment: This should be a comment as it does not attempt to solve the problem, only request clarification.

Comment: I din't ask any info from the user, how can  it be a clarification? And it does help solve the problem... lease don't downvote unneccesarily and then copy others posts into your "comments"

Comment: `Do an alert for the below and see if it is "index.html" in smaller case?` That's a question. What if it does indeed return `index.html` - as the OP already states?

Comment: "Do an alert for the below and see if it is "index.html" in smaller case" is not a question, I put a question mark by mistake, edited

Comment: Ok, in this case it's now a command guiding the user to debug the code. Again, that is a comment, not an answer. I'm not trying to annoy you here, I just want you to understand how to effectively help people on this site.

Comment: well to answer your question, it does return 'index.html' when i output it into console. If statement validates and passes into the contents within. IE: console.log(...) works in the if statement, just the addClass/removeClass code doesn't change any visual appearances.

Comment: Because $('.nav') will give you an array not a single element, even if its asingle element, it is an array with a single element. use $('.nav')[0].removeClass

Comment: Rory, I got it, thanks, I am also just trying to help people, just new to SO, so learning it hard way I guess

Answer (score 1):

use

```
$(doucment).bind("load", function(){
 alert("page is loaded");
});
```

if that doesn't work, maybe your jquery isn't working then you could use this javascript function and it'll surely work

```
window.onload = function() {
 alert("page is loaded");
}
```

If it actually alerts then you should probably check and ensure the path name of your page is actually "index.html" by testing what the function actually returns for the page(without the match) and printing the value out then testing the equality of the path name to the printed value instead. Hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found the issue, I was using jquery to link my index.html to a header.html (which I did to make global edits to the header much easier than changing all 10 pages' headers). Everything else in my .js script works on the header but I guess I'm stupid and didn't realize that it was only detecting whether the index.html loaded or not, and not the header.html. Thanks! Sorry for the trouble... lesson learned